# Making sense of multiple like buttons/boxes and Facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

I have a slightly confusing setup on my site right now with:

- A like button with the data-ref attribute set to the root domain of my site
- A like box with date-ref set to a Facebook page I created for my site.

These obviously leads to different things, as the like button has 2.7k likes while the like box/Facebook page has around 600. This last number is also the number of likes I see on my regular Facebook page.

Now I also noticed that I have a second Facebook page saying it is the administration page for my webpage. The page has never been used to post anything, and it doesn't seem to be visible to anyone but me. This page has 700 likes.

I've been reading documentation on this stuff, but I'm not feeling confident about merging the pages or anything just yet, so I have a couple of questions I'm hoping someone with more Facebook experience than me can answer:

1. Where does this 700 number come from? It's not displayed on either my like button or my like box.
2. Is there any way for me to combine these three different counts into one?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The 700 is the count of people that liked the URL after you created the admin page which represents that URL - this is irrelevant now as that functionality is deprecated. ( see the link CBroe provided: developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration
- It is not possible to migrate fans from one object or page to another, except as was allowed during the migration period outlined in that document, if you didn't migrate during that period you cannot move the fans of the site/domain to be fans of the Facebook page instead

Comment: Ouch, that sucks. Could you perhaps also help share some light on why there is a 2k diff between the number of likes displayed beside my like button and the number of likes on the admin page?

Comment: The like button includes shares, comments, etc, and the admin page only included likes (and only started counting at the point the admin page was created)- the number on the like button is explained at the bottom of the like button docs ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ )

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Btw: On my admin page I can still go to the "Resources" section of my admin page, choose "Merge duplicate pages" and my other page comes up as an alternative.